# KnockOut validation between two dates?

Tags: jquery, validation, knockout.js

I have two textboxes which are  binded with Datepicker binding handlers to show a datepicker on click on textbox (DD/MM/YYYY).

My two textboxes are `From` and `To` textboxes . As name suggests i expect a validation to work like `To` date is always greater than `From` .

I tried googling but sadly my efforts aren't enough to grab the right info .

To be frank i have done this validation using jquery with splitting,comparing like that which is bit loopy and complex and most importantly its not a knockout way .

I am trying to do things in a KnockOut way , any suggestions are appreciated .

**Update :** i am trying something like this

```
self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([

            self.ToDate.extend({ 
                validation: {
                    validator: function (val, someOtherVal) {
                         Date.parse(val) > Date.parse(someOtherVal()); 
       var date1 = val.split('/'); var date2 = someOtherVal().split('/');
      var TDate = new Date(date1[2], date1[1], date1[0]); var FDate = new Date(date1[2],             date1[1], date1[0]);
                         if (Date.parse(Tdate) > Date.parse(FDate))
                         { return true; } else { return false; }
                    },
                    message: 'Must be greater than FromDate',
                    params: self.FromDate
                } 
            })
        ]);
```

Well code looks messy . one issue i am facing with above code when OnLoad if i have empty `val` which is `ToDate` . I am  getting error at `split` which is rightly so . is there any way i can restrict this error .

Answer (score 1):

Make both of your to/from values you bind your inputs to computed read/write observables which are writing to a private observable in your view model.

```
self._StartTime = ko.observable();
self.StartTime = ko.computed({
    read: function () { return self._StartTime(); },
    write: function (newStartTime) {
        if (!newStartTime) {
            self._StartTime(null);
            self._EndTime(null);
            return;
        }
        // other code here
    }
});
```

Do the same with your end time and you can gain access to both parameters in your computed regions when read/writes are done from either input field...

Comment: I have complete access to dates but i am looking for something short and cute as knockout always been comparing date rather going in a hard way like i done above . I done using normal approcah `(value:ToDate)` rather using `computed` and calling `(value:computeddate)` . either way i get access to dates but comapring been issue . my format `(DD/MM/YYYY)`

Comment: well, if you want to compare them, you're going to have to write some code to do it...at least some validation logic...having a computed set up to manage this is how to leverage 'cute'

Answer (score 1):

Using moment you can do it very easily

```
ko.validation.rules['dateGreaterThen'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        var d1 = moment(val, 'yy/mm/dd');
        var d2 = moment(otherVal(), 'yy/mm/dd');
        return d1 >= d2
    },
    message: function (val) {
        var date = moment(val()).format('yy/mm/dd')
        return 'The date must be greater then or equal to ' + date
    }
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Comment: ah yes it can be done this way right . i am thinking about binding in cshtml using moment which is not required rightly mentioned . curious doubt what happens if `val` is `undefined` will i get any error at `moment(val, 'yy/mm/dd')`

Comment: use a condition if val is undefined display some other message. If you add required validation this will be solved easily.